# How to create a TCP server-client program that will send 200 tcp flows from the source to the destination?

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu, tcp, client-server

I want to create a simple TCP Server-client program for my Ubuntu 12.10 where the source will be able to send 200 (or, any n) no. of flows to the destination? I am looking for some sort of socket programming. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For next questions I recomend you to first try googleing it. There are thousands of examples on the internet.

Modify this one. You only have to modify the while at the bottom of the program. The port should go in the line commented.

### Client.c

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int sockfd,n,m=0;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   char sendline[1000];
   char recvline[1000];

   if (argc != 3)
   {
      printf("usage:  client <IP address> <Number of messagges>\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(argv[1]);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000); //Port for the TCP Client

   connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

   while (m<=argv[2]) //While that has to be modified
   {
      fgets(sendline, 10000,stdin;
      sendto(sockfd,sendline,strlen(sendline),0,
             (struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
      n=recvfrom(sockfd,recvline,10000,0,NULL,NULL);
      recvline[n]=0;
      fputs(recvline,stdout);
      m++;
   }
}
```

### Server.c

```
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
   int listenfd,connfd,n;
   struct sockaddr_in servaddr,cliaddr;
   socklen_t clilen;
   pid_t     childpid;
   char mesg[1000];

   listenfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

   bzero(&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));
   servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   servaddr.sin_port=htons(32000);//Port that has to be modified
   bind(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

   listen(listenfd,1024);

   for(;;)
   {
      clilen=sizeof(cliaddr);
      connfd = accept(listenfd,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);

      if ((childpid = fork()) == 0)
      {
         close (listenfd);

         for(;;)
         {
            n = recvfrom(connfd,mesg,1000,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,&clilen);
            sendto(connfd,mesg,n,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr,sizeof(cliaddr));
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
            mesg[n] = 0;
            printf("Received the following:\n");
            printf("%s",mesg);
            printf("-------------------------------------------------------\n");
         }

      }
      close(connfd);
   }
}
```

Source: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/
I've also googled it.

Have a nice code!

Comment: Could you tell me why you're using infinite loops here? This makes the program run infinitely - whereas I want the server to run for the number of times I specify in the client.

Comment: The second argument you pass to the program when you run it especifies the number of packets you want to send. It is exactly what ypu asked for, instead of the code inside the while, what I really don't know what you want to do.

Comment: Yes, I passed that - still it was running into an infinite loop. However, there was a small mistake - I rectified it. It's working now - thanks!

Comment: Hi, just faced a problem in this approach. It's working for 4 or less no of times, but when I wanna send the file for 300-400 times, it stops after a certain no. of iterations(Sometimes 3, sometimes 17)! Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of examples of client/server programming in C on Internet.
One of first Google answers gives [this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/c-socket-programming/) where you have an example you can use to do what you want after adapting it.